# Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions on Wordpress for medium size

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress Media Settings the Thumbnail size we can crop thumbnail to exact dimensions.

But for the `Medium size` no option to get exact dimensions. There have a way to force exact dimensions for **medium size**?

If yes, how to implement to the `functions.php`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want medium images to be cropped instead of scaled, like you can choose for the thumbnail size in the options page (but not for medium or large sizes), [you can set the `medium_crop` option to `true` in your `functions.php`](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/force-crop-to-medium-size):

```
if(false === get_option("medium_crop")) {
    add_option("medium_crop", "1");
} else {
    update_option("medium_crop", "1");
}
```

Comment: I wanted to be really certain :-) Remember that this will only affect **future** images, but not those that already exist.

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than mine. Cool solution Jan! :)

Answer (score 4):

As of now, [there's a better way to do it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/30966). You can overwrite the default image sizes—namely *thumbnail*, *medium* and *large*—using the `add_image_size` function.

**Examples:**

```
// Set "Thumbnail" image size
if( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, false );

}

// Set "Medium" and "Large" image sizes
if( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {

    add_image_size( 'medium', 300, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'large', 1024, 9999, false );

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', create_function( '', 'add_image_size( "cropped_medium", 300, 150, true );' ) );
```

The arguments are size name, width, height, and whether to force a crop.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /functions.php on line 77

Comment: John forgot a comma between the `'init'` and the `create_function`.